# Ajax response is gzip compressed - Prototype, Firefox can't handle it

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototypejs, gzip

I'm trying to query a web service (with JavaScript, prototype). The server responds with XML, but compresses it; headers are set appropriately.

Under Safari 4, everything is fine. The response is decompressed and JavaScript can deal with the data.

Under Firefox 3.5.8, no data is returned to JavaScript!

Code:

```
     var req = new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
        asynchronous: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        method: 'post',
        postBody: xmlString,
        onSuccess: function(t) {
            // debug, place response into textarea to show
            $('responseText').value = t.responseText;
        }
    });
```

This is the response, as I trace it on the network:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Date: Fri, 05 Mar 2010 14:10:51 GMT.
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny6 with Suhosin-Patch.
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny6.
Vary: Accept-Encoding.
Content-Encoding: gzip.
Content-Length: 2104.
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100.
Connection: Keep-Alive.
Content-Type: text/xml.
.
............]s......W`.3...H&A.$.Q.^[.:....... (and so on ...)
```

Any idea why this is happening? What can I do about it?

I tried setting the 'Accept-Encoding' header in the request, can't get it working properly. Besides, the response can be rather large, meaning: it's good that it is compressed by the server.

Comment: are you positive that firefox decompresses the data when you make the request normally (without Ajax.Request)?

Comment: The "Vary" header is for HTTP *requests*, not *responses.*

Comment: Of course it is. The browser sends request header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' as one would expect it of a current browser (I did not show the request headers). And the response carries the correct response header 'Content-Encoding: gzip'. It's just that it's not being decompressed by Firefox!

Comment: Why are you using `asynchronous: false`? That's highly not recommended...

Comment: Hi Josh - didn't know it's not recommended. I'll rethink my application logic, see if I can live without it. Do you think this is related to the problem I'm experiencing though?

Comment: I'm not sure. I swear I have parsed gzipped responses before, I was going to write a quick test and post it when I get a moment.

Comment: Pointy, Vary is used for responses.  Hank, this should work.  Do you possibly have a link to a page showing the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox fails to decompress gzip files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292868/firefox-fails-to-decompress-gzip-files)

Comment: @PaulSweatte, Did you read it completely? Its not a duplicate of the question you linked.