# Using the new facebook graph api, ajax calls returns null (empty)

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery

Im trying out the new graph api for facebook. I'm trying to fetch some data using jquery ajax.
This is a sample of  my javascript code, very basic...

```
var mUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552';
   $.ajax({
        url: mUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
          $('#test').html(data);
          alert(data);

      },
      error: function(data, e1, e2) {
        $('#hello').html(e1);  
      }
   });
```

The url is to a page that does not need access tokens (try it using a browser), but the success function returns an empty object or null.

What am I doing wrong? Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 10):

I have covered this and asked this question before. I made a quick [tutorial](http://www.prettyklicks.com/blog/making-a-facebook-feed-using-the-graph-api-json-and-jquery/291/) which covers exactly this and **explains it all**.

In short:
JSON is not made for cross domain usage according to its same-origin policy. However the work around is to use JSONP which we can do in jQuery using the supported callback parameter in facebook's graph api. We can do so by adding the parameter onto your url like

`https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?callback=?`

by using the callback=? jQuery automatically changes the ? to wrap the json in a function call which then allows jQuery to parse the data successfully.

Also try using $.getJSON method.

Comment: I think its important to note that the Facebook graph API does support JSONP enabling this to work.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something similar, in testing I was able to get a working result which I saved on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8R7J8/1/

Script:

```
var facebookGraphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552';
$.ajax({
    url: facebookGraphURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status) {
      $( '#output' ).html('Username: ' + data.username);
    },
    error: function(data, e1, e2) {
      $( '#output' ).html(e2);
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="output">BorkBorkBork</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

...The Graph API supports JSONP. Simply pass callback=methodname as an extra parameter and the returned content will be wrapped in a function call, allowing you to use a dynamically inserted script tag to grab that data.
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=253084#p253084

Answer (score 0):

You can't do cross-domain AJAX requests like that due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Instead, use Facebook's [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), which is based on a script tag.

Comment: It's not crossdomain related . I can see the json data from Facebook using a network analyzer (wireshark)

This thread is about similar problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387271/ajax-response-is-gzip-compressed-prototype-firefox-cant-handle-it

Maybe is related to gzip , but not sure even about that ... i have a similar call to youtube 
var url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+query+"&max-results=30&v=2&alt=jsonc&format=5";

and it works despite the same gzip encoding as facebook call

Comment: well ... after some hour of investigation i'm even more confused :)
if Firefox implements same-origin policy by hiding responseText then it can be that (im going to give you back the 1 point as 24h passed)