# Parsing JSON with GWT and GAE?

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, gwt

I want to pull in JSON data from https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=foo&type=group. I read about using [JSONP with GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_for_json_mashups.html), but it doesn't look like I can make that work with Facebook. Thus, I'm making a call to GAE, which opens up a URL connection to Facebook.

```
   try {
        String url = String.format(SEARCH_URL_FORMAT, URLEncoder.encode(param, CHARSET));
        URLConnection urlConn = new URL(url).openConnection();
        InputStream response = urlConn.getInputStream();

        JsonObject data = JsonObject.parse(new InputStreamReader(response, CHARSET));
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid JSON returned by Facebook.");
    }
```

Unfortunately, this causes the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/json/JsonException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You can use JSON-P with Facebook's Graph API: [Using the new facebook graph api, ajax calls returns null (empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138718/using-the-new-facebook-graph-api-ajax-calls-returns-null-empty/3379918#3379918) (beware that the GWT documentation is outdated: use the [JsonpRequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) instead)
- AppEngine won't let you do everything (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html ). For fetching URLs, it provides a dedicated [URL Fetch service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/).