# Firefox fails to decompress gzip files

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, http-headers, gzip, mime-types

I have .gz files stored on AWS s3.

Using the s3 REST-API, I'm generating authenticated links that point to individual files. I'm also setting the content-header options such that browsers requesting these urls will decompress and download the gzipped files as attachments.

The generated s3 url looks like so:

```
https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/PATH_TO/file.ext.gz
  ?AWSAccessKeyId=MY_KEY
  &Expires=DATE_TIME
  &Signature=MY_SIGNATURE
  &response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22file.ext%22
  &response-content-encoding=gzip
  &response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
  &x-amz-security-token=MY_TOKEN
```

The links behave as expected in: (All on OSX) Chrome (42.0.2311), Safari (8.0.6), Opera (29.0),

but NOT Firefox (38.0.1)

Firefox downloads and renames the file correctly but fails to decompress the gzipped file.

The response headers of a GET request to the authenticated urls look like so:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="file.ext"
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:928
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:SOME_DATE_TIME
ETag:"MY_ETAG"
Last-Modified:SOME_OTHER_DATE_TIME
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-expiration:expiry-date="ANOTHER_DATE_TIME"
x-amz-id-2:MY_AMZ_ID
x-amz-request-id:MY_AMZ_REQUEST_ID
x-amz-server-side-encryption:AES256
```

Does Firefox look for different headers and/or header values to indicate decompression?

Comment: Have you tested this on a gzipped file that does not have a `.gz` extension?   What about using a more accurate `Content-Type:` for the particular file, than the generic `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: What in the world... Removing the `.gz` extension (renaming the file in s3, but not actually decompressing), fixes the issue, now all 4 browsers work. I feel uncomfortable that I'm now storing files in s3 that are gzipped but with non-gzipped extensions but I guess it's better than the prior situation...  @Michael-sqlbot feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.  Also if you have any insight into this behavior I'd be forever grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution appears to be removing `.gz` from the end of the filename.

It's a common misconfiguration to set `Content-Encoding: gzip` on `.gz` files when you intend for the end user to download -- and end up with -- a `.gz` file; e.g. downloading a `.tar.gz` of source package.

This isn't what you are doing... It's the opposite, essentially... but I suspect you're seeing a symptom of an attempt to address that issue.

In fact, the configuration I described should only be the case when you gzipped an already-gzipped file (which, of course, you shouldn't do)... but it was entrenched for a long time by (iirc) default Apache web server configurations.  Old bug reports seem to suggest that the Firefox developers had a hard time grasping what should be done with `Content-Encoding: gzip`, particularly with regard to downloads.  They were a bit obsessed, it seems, with the thought that the browser should not undo the content encoding when saving to disk, since saving to disk wasn't the same as "rendering" the downloaded content.  That, to me, is nonsense, a too-literal interpretation of an RFC.

I suspect what you see is a legacy of that old issue.

Contrary to your conception, it's quite correct to store a file with `Content-Encoding: gzip` *without* a `.gz` extension... arguably, in fact, it's *more* correct to store such content without a `.gz` extension, because the `.gz` implies (at least to Firefox, apparently) that the downloading user should want the compressed content downloaded and saved in the compressed form.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Background to compressed content**

Michael's changing of the file extension solves the problem is because the important step is to change the `Content-Type` header to reflect the **underlying  content** within the compressed file, rather than that of the compressed file itself.

In many webservers, the *mime types* are detected based on file extension - for example, you may have a mime type of `application/gzip` corresponding to `.gz` file extensions (on a default Debian install of nginx, this can be found within `/etc/nginx/mime.types`). Your server will then set headers as `Content-Type: application/gzip` for the files matching this mime type.

If your browser receives a `Content-Type` header suggesting binary compressed content is on it's way rather than the text within the compressed file, it will assume it's not for human consumption and may not display it. Mine (`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0`) didn't.

**2. Header adjustment**

1. Set a `Content-Encoding: 'gzip'` header
2. Set `Content-Type: 'text/plain'` header for files you want displayed in plain text

The browser (if gzip compression is supported), should decompress and display the content for the client.

**3. Real world example**

`/usr/share/doc` contains text documentation, many of which have also been gzip compressed.

By adding the following to the nginx `server {}` block, you can enable transparent decompression on the client:

```
# local documentation access
location /doc {
    alias /usr/share/doc;
    autoindex on; # allow dir listings
    allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; # anyone outside is forbidden

    # display .gz content in text on the browser
    location ~ \.gz {
        default_type text/plain;
        add_header Content-Encoding: 'gzip';
    }

}
```